# Add event listener to multiple generated elements

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm trying to make Tic-Tac-Toe for my school in pure JS and based on CSS and HTML GUI. I know it's probably not the best approach, but I thought it may work. Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all.

I'm trying to generate whole board by JS in `Board.generate()`, because I want to make my board resizeable, and then add event listeners to every generated cell, but this isn't working. Onclick is called only on the last element and not on the previous ones. I think I could bypass this problem by making a function, but I want to understand why my code doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```js
class Board {
  constructor(size) {
    this.size = size;
 
    this.cells = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
      this.cells[x] = [];
      for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        this.cells[x][y] = new Cell(x, y, null);
      }
    }
  }
 
  generate() {
    document.getElementById('game').innerHTML = '<div id="board"></div>';
 
    let boardEl = document.getElementById('board');
 
    for (let y = 0; y < this.size; y++) {
      boardEl.innerHTML += '<div id="r' + y + '" class="board-row"></div>';
      let rowEl = document.getElementById('r' + y);
 
      for (let x = 0; x < this.size; x++)
        this.cells[x][y].addElement(rowEl);
    }
  }
}
 
class Cell {
  constructor(x, y, mark) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.mark = mark;
    this.id = 'c' + x + y;
    this.element = null;
  }
 
  addElement(rowEl) {
    rowEl.innerHTML += '<div id="' + this.id + '" class="board-cell"> CELL </div>';
    this.element = document.getElementById(this.id);
    this.element.addEventListener('click', () => this.clicked(), false);
  }
 
  clicked() {
    console.log(this.x, this.y, ' CLICKED!');
  }
}
 
window.onload = function () {
  var game = new Board(3);
  game.generate();
};
```

```html
<style>
  .board-cell {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    background: white;
    color:black;
  }
</style>
<div id="container" class="fullscreen">

  <div id="game" class="fullscreen">

    <!-- Generated board -->

  </div>

</div>
```

I know my code is a mess right now, but I was just frustrated, and it's only a sketch, I'll work on it.
Also, sorry for my English if I made some mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you set the `innerHTML` property you are overwriting any previous HTML that was set there. This includes concatenation assignment, because

```
element.innerHTML += '<b>Hello</b>';
```

is the same as writing

```
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + '<b>Hello</b>';
```

This means all handlers not attached via HTML attributes will be "detached", since the elements they were attached to no longer exist, and a new set of elements has taken their place. To keep all your previous event handlers, you have to append elements without overwriting any previous HTML. The best way to do this is to use DOM creation functions such as createElement and appendChild:

```
let divEl  = document.createElement("div");
divEl.innerHTML = "CELL";   
divEl.className = 'board-cell'
divEl.id = this.id;
rowEl.appendChild(divEl);
```

The same is for row div elements:

```
let divRowEl  = document.createElement("div");
divRowEl.className = 'board-row'
divRowEl.id = 'r' + y;
boardEl.appendChild(divRowEl);
```

```js
class Board {
  constructor(size) {
    this.size = size;
 
    this.cells = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
      this.cells[x] = [];
      for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        this.cells[x][y] = new Cell(x, y, null);
      }
    }
  }
 
  generate() {
    
    document.getElementById('game').innerHTML = '<div id="board"></div>';
 
    let boardEl = document.getElementById('board');
 
    for (let y = 0; y < this.size; y++) {
      let divRowEl  = document.createElement("div");
      divRowEl.className = 'board-row'
      divRowEl.id = 'r' + y;
      boardEl.appendChild(divRowEl);
      let rowEl = document.getElementById('r' + y);
      
      for (let x = 0; x < this.size; x++)
        this.cells[x][y].addElement(rowEl);
    }
  }
}
 
class Cell {
  constructor(x, y, mark) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.mark = mark;
    this.id = 'c' + x + y;
    this.element = null;
  }
 
  addElement(rowEl) {
    let divEl  = document.createElement("div");
    divEl.innerHTML = "CELL" + this.id;   
    divEl.className = 'board-cell'
    divEl.id = this.id;
    divEl.addEventListener('click', () => this.clicked(), false);
    rowEl.appendChild(divEl);
  }
 
  clicked() {
    console.log(this.x, this.y, ' CLICKED!');
  }
}
 
window.onload = function () {
  var game = new Board(3);
  game.generate();
};
```

```html
<style>
  .board-cell {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    background: white;
    color:black;
  }
</style>
<div id="container" class="fullscreen">

  <div id="game" class="fullscreen">

    <!-- Generated board -->

  </div>

</div>
```